# Questasim tool showing error after updating code and re running for schematic

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, questasim

Problem related to Model Sim Questa tool. (System verilog)

I have run the code in Questa Sim, then check the schematic of that verilog code.
But again I changed something in that code and try to run the schematic, i got an error [No Design Loaded]
Also one more error
"error could not open the database because no design is currently loaded"

Please help me to solve this issue.
I'm using Questa Sim-64 10.6c[image]

Answer (score -1):

From the attached picture it seems that you have some files that are not compiled (? next to the name), you should compile the design and reload it first.

Comment: That are empty files not related to the file which I want to simulate.